# jsp encoding display issue

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, tomcat, utf-8

I am finding a issue where the data is encoded properly in the controller and compiled `jsp`, but is not displaying properly within an alert statement (or on the page). Please see the following configurations.

- tomcat server property

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

- java controller - hard coded value

```
renderRequest.setAttribute("general", "¯_(ツ)_/¯ ¯_(ツ)_/¯");
```

- first line in jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

- jsp scriptlet to display session attribute

```
<%
    String general = (String)request.getAttribute("general");
    System.out.println("#### general is: " + general);
%> 

#### general is: ¯_(ツ)_/¯ ¯_(ツ)_/¯
```

- html in jsp

```
<p>¯_(ツ)_/¯ ¯_(ツ)_/¯</p>

<pre>'<%= request.getAttribute("general") %>'</pre>
```

- compiled jsp snippet showing encoded chars

```
out.write("\t\t<p>¯_(ツ)_/¯ ¯_(ツ)_/¯</p>\r\n");
```

- all display

```
Â¯_(ãƒ„)_/Â¯ Â¯_(ãƒ„)_/Â¯
```

- web.xml configuration

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
```

- server.xml configuration

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="7070" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

What sort of simple configuration am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have a `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` in your html `<head>` and is your JSP really saved as UTF-8 (text encoding)?

Comment: Thank you, yes sir.  The Eclipse IDE is saved as UTF-8 in the Resource > Text file encoding properties and the following tag <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"> is in the <head> of the jsp.

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple oversight to also include the filter-mapping along with the filter (slaps forehead).  Added the following to the web.xml config along with the previous updates and all worked.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```